# Pass array of bytes cross-appdomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, binaryformatter

So just posting this here to see if a solution exists or whether my approach will have to be rethinked.

Currently I have a main application, which creates a child appDomain and loads an assembly into that appDomain, the assembly itself is dynamically generated and could have all kinds of serializable objects.

What I would like to be able to do, is serialize the object in the child appDomain with binaryFormatter, and then deserialize it in the main appDomain without having to load the dynamically generated assembly into my main appDomain aswell.

Example.

Using code to create a binary stream in the child appDomain.

```
private byte[] WriteToByteArray()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            var f = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            f.Serialize(ms, _value);
            var binArray = ms.GetBuffer();
            writer.Write(binArray.Length);
            writer.Write(binArray);
        }
    }
    return stream.GetBuffer();
}
```

then in the main appDomain

```
private object ReadFromByteArray(byte[] binaryArray)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(binaryArray))
    {
        var f = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return f.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

This code would work if either it was performed in same appDomain or the generated assembly was loaded into both appDomains, but will fail with "Could not load file or assembly" when performing Deserialize in Main appDomain where assembly was not loaded and type does not exists

My question however is, is it possible to somehow deserialize the byte[] by pointing to the child AppDomain as the source of info for the objects type?

I hope I'm making sense

Comment: Nope that is not possible.

Comment: If an object of type `T` is to live in an AppDomain, then type `T` must be loaded in that AppDomain. You can serialize the object in any way you like, but deserializing it in a domain where the assembly containing the object's type is not loaded won't work. The question would be: why do you even need that ability in the first place? If the receiving AppDomain cannot know the type of the object (and hence can do nothing meaningful with it) why does it even need to be a custom object, as opposed to (say) an XML blob or a dictionary of properties?

Comment: I am sorry for the edit, I misunderstood the intent of passing the data cross-appdomain. What OP wants is impossible, as stated in the previous comments

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I just needed to be sure I'm not missing something before I go in another direction.
The reason for the inquiry was due to the fact that I wanted to avoid making unnecessary cross appDomain calls